# Windows authentification: connect with other account

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication

I'm using asp.net mvc to make a web application using Windows authentification.

I want to add the possibility to connect with other account in the AD ,

this is my code :

```
public ActionResult ChangeUser()
        {
            HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["TSWA-Last-User"];

            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false || cookie == null || StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(User.Identity.Name, cookie.Value))
            {
                string name = string.Empty;

                if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
                {
                    name = User.Identity.Name;
                }

                cookie = new HttpCookie("TSWA-Last-User", name);
                Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);

                Response.AppendHeader("Connection", "close");
                Response.StatusCode = 401; // Unauthorized;
                Response.Clear();




                Response.Write("refresh page to try again...");
                Response.End();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
```

the code is working fine it shows me a pop up to enter usernam and password and the user get changed

The Problem is :  when i click in cancel button (in the windows pop up) it redirect me to the 401 message , what i want is  when a user click in cancel  he shoul be redirected to some index action

Comment: Use "authentication filter" to achieve this approach. It is a better and clean option.

Comment: i'm using asp.net mv4 i dont think  authentication filters work  with  mvc4